# How to make sure we have same number of columns in train and production data in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have trained a pyspark model and saved pipeline and model in drive.

Now I am trying to predict for future datasets by loading pipeline.

```
pipelineModel = PipelineModel.load("s3://data-production/pipelineModel_v1")

new_test= pipelineModel.transform(new_df1)
```

Here I am getting error in my production dataset .
How to make sure columns in training dataset be replicated to production data as well in Pyspark?

Comment: Maybe adding assertion checks would help alleviate issues? In other words, before saving the model, ensure that the data is formatted correctly.

Comment: I have 1000 plus columns , should i save column names also?